# How to disable auto-complete while in lisp mode?

Tags: autocompletion

I try to find which mode displays a popup menu with a list of candidates while entering code in emacs lisp.  Whenever I type 2 letters a popup menu appears.  I would like to disable it in lisp or prog mode.

[image]

Comment: Which Emacs 'distribution/starter-kit' do you use?

Comment: Popping up a menu like that is not the default Emacs behavior. To find out which code (e.g. package) you're using that's causing that behavior, and then to look into how to avoid/prevent it in a given context, *bisect your init file*.

Comment: I was using Corfu and Company.  I just disabled Company and let Corfu while editing emacs-lisp code.  +Now it is ok.